# I am following this but cant seem to get it to work

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://www.weblinc.com/labs/jquery-parallax/

I have followed that, and it doesn't work for me, looking at the source code of the demo, it's nothing like the tutorial, does it work for anyone else? or is it broken

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css"/>
    <script script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.parallax.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script>
$('.bg-far').parallax({ speed: 0.2, axis: 'x' }); 
$('.bg-close').parallax({ speed: 0.5, axis: 'x' });
</script>
    <div class="bg-far bg"></div> 
<div class="bg-close bg"></div> 
    </body>
</html>


.bg { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
height: 7000px; 
width: 100%; 
background-repeat: repeat; 
} 

.bg-far { 
background-image: url(bg1.png); 
opacity: 0.8; 
z-index: 5; 
} 

.bg-close { 
background-image: url(bg2.png); 
z-index: 10; 
}
```

here is the jquery:

```
// jquery.parallax.js
// @weblinc, @jsantell, (c) 2012

;(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.parallax = function ( userSettings ) {
        var options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.parallax.defaults, userSettings );

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this   = $(this),
                isX     = options.axis === 'x',
                origPos = ( $this.css( 'background-position' ) || '' ).split(' '),
                origX   = $this.css( 'background-position-x' ) || origPos[ 0 ],
                origY   = $this.css( 'background-position-y' ) || origPos[ 1 ],
                dist    = function () {
                    return -$( window )[ isX ? 'scrollLeft' : 'scrollTop' ]();
                };
            $this
                .css( 'background-attachment', 'fixed' )
                .addClass( 'inview' );

            $this.bind('inview', function ( e, visible ) {
                $this[ visible ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'inview' );
            });

            $( window ).bind( 'scroll', function () {
                if ( !$this.hasClass( 'inview' )) { return; }
                var xPos = isX ? ( dist() * options.speed ) + 'px' : origX,
                    yPos = isX ? origY : ( dist() * options.speed ) + 'px';
                $this.css( 'background-position', xPos + ' ' + yPos );
            });
        });
    };

    $.fn.parallax.defaults = {
        start: 0,
        stop: $( document ).height(),
        speed: 1,
        axis: 'x'
    };

})( jQuery );
```

does not move like in the demo

Comment: ... or post your code here?

Comment: I will post code in a sec, but I mean you have it in the link, I was asking if the code in the tutorial is wrong but ok

Comment: @user2469932 People shouldn't have to go to different websites to help you. Post your code here and we can tell you where it is wrong.

Comment: Did you included JQuery ?

Comment: Maybe you could check your console...?!  And then think about including jQuery

Comment: Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/5SxZB/1/

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, it's just highly dependent on the order you perform the steps in. If you have the jQuery code *before* the elements they won't exist when it executes, nothing will be selected, and the code won't do anything. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Declare your HTML elements first, and put the `<script>` tag to initialise the plugin after them (this is the order they're done in the example).

   ```
   <div class="bg-far bg"></div> 
   <div class="bg-close bg"></div> 

   <script>
       $('.bg-far').parallax({ speed: 0.2, axis: 'x' }); 
       $('.bg-close').parallax({ speed: 0.5, axis: 'x' });
   </script>
   ```
2. Use a DOM ready handler.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.bg-far').parallax({ speed: 0.2, axis: 'x' }); 
       $('.bg-close').parallax({ speed: 0.5, axis: 'x' });
   });
   ```

2 would generally be the preferred method since then you don't have to worry about where the code is in relation to the elements it interacts with.

You'll also need to include `jquery.js` *before* the `jquery.parallax.js` file.

Comment: hmm, declaring the script after the html now made the images sit still and no scroll at all

Comment: @user2469932 Are you including jQuery itself (not just the parallax plugin) now? There's no `<script>` tag to do that in what you posted in the question.

Comment: yes I'm including the jquery itself `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>`